# ¿Cómo ejecutar dos transiciones simultáneas (a la vez) desde JavaScript? ¿Cómo situar un elemento en el centro de la pantalla?

Tags: javascript, transacciones

Estoy desarrollando una web en la que necesito que **circunferencias cubran toda la pantalla** al ser pulsadas, para eso he creado el método *dotFillScreen()*.

Mi problema es que se ejecuta solamente una de las dos transiciones, y cuando la comento la otra ya si se ejecuta. Entonces ¿Como puedo ejecutar las 2 simultaneamente?

Por otro lado he logrado trasladar el elemento hasta el centro de la pantalla, pero estoy seguro que existe alguna solución más elegante.

He intentado comentar el código lo máximo para facilitar la ayuda, gracias de antemano.

```
/*
Función que amplía un elemento circular hasta que cubre toda la pantalla

    1. Cálculos
        1.1 centro de la pantalla
        1.2 la posición del elemento 
        1.3 cuanto ha de crecer
    2. Establecer el tiempo de transición
    3. Dos transiciones simultáneas
        3.1 trasladar al centro de la pantalla
        3.2 Escalar el tamaño del elemento
    4. Concluir la promesa tras el tiempo establecido

*/
function dotFillScreen(e, time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var dot=e.target;

        //dimensiones de la pantalla
        var h = window.innerHeight;
        var w = window.innerWidth;

        //posición del objeto
        var x = getOffset( dot ).left;
        var y = getOffset( dot ).top;

        //cantidad de pixeles hasta el centro de la pantalla
        var movex = ( (w/2)-x );
        var movey = ( (h/2)-y );

        //hayamos la longitud inicial del elemento
        var l = dot.clientWidth;

        //calculamos el radio que debe tener para ocupar toda la pantalla
        var rad = Math.pow(
            (Math.pow(h,2)+Math.pow(w,2)),
            1/2
        );

        //La proporción que tiene que crecer 
        var scale = (rad/l);

        //Fijamos el tiempo de la transición en el establecido por parámetro
        dot.style.transition = "transform "+time+"s";
        
        //ejecutamos las transiciones para centrar y ampliar el círculo cubriendo toda la pantalla
        dot.style.transform = "scale("+scale+")";
        dot.style.transform = "translate("+movex+"px,"+movey+"px)";

        //tras el tiempo que tarda en cubrir la pantalla ya podemos confirmar la promesa
        setTimeout(() => {resolve();}, time*1000);
    })
}

//Función que calcula la posición de un elemento
function getOffset( el ) {
    var _x = 0;
    var _y = 0;
    while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
          _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
          _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
          el = el.offsetParent;
    }
    return { top: _y, left: _x };
}
```